Correct syntax to reference dynamic column name with SSJS Rows.Update() function
When the column name of a Data Extension is unknown and data needs to be written to that column what is the correct syntax as the following do not seem to work,
Where e.num is some dynamic value like 1 or 2 or 3 etc
and payloadStr is a stringified object
var colWrite = 'Column' + e.num;
DEName.Rows.Update({colWrite:payloadStr}, ['CampaignID'], [UniqueCampaignNameRow]);

returns with
Failed "There was an error Updating the row(s)."

Trying the same with JS type syntax
var colWrite = 'Column' + e.num;
DEName.Rows.Update({[colWrite]:payloadStr}, ['CampaignID'], [UniqueCampaignNameRow]);

Returns a 500 error (internal server)

just found the answer which tested and works (thanks chatgpt)
var colWrite = 'Column' + e.num;
var updateObject = {};
updateObject[colWrite] = payloadStr;
DEName.Rows.Update(updateObject, ['CampaignID'], [UniqueCampaignNameRow]);

